# UNISWAP/PANCAKESWAP get list of LP holders of a token

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

Is there a simple way to get a list of LP-holders for a particular Uniswap/Pancakeswap pair? I need to know the addresses of people who has provided liquidity for my token (which has been already added to UNI/PAN)

Since the Pair contract has only balanceOf() function which is mapping, it's impossible to read the whole list without knowing the mapping keys

The only somehow humane way I think to do this - is to use Infura (or some other node), subscribe to 'Pair.mint()' event and trigger some of my contract functions when this event occurs. But I find this method pretty ugly

Maybe there are some better ways? Thanks

PS. leaving the [link to 'Pair' contract](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol) of Pancakeswap here, just in case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the list of LP token holders is not different from getting a list of any ERC-20 token holders. The LP token is not different from other tokens: it has its own ERC-20 contract, contract address, methods, etc.

The recommended method is to build a database of all ERC-20 `Transfer` events, keep it updated in real-time and then from this database extract your snapshots.

[Here is one generic get ERC-20 token holders answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64814/620).

You could also try to solve the problem with [TheGraph subquery](https://thegraph.com/docs/define-a-subgraph#from-an-existing-contract). You can also construct a Dune Analytics query like [this one](https://duneanalytics.com/queries/15341). In both of these cases, there is a third party that maintains an existing large database with efficient indexing that you can query against.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Special thanks for providing the explanation/examples <3